# sending the verification code to the SMS and not to the application

Tags: telegram-api, wtelegramclient

is it possible to define how the verification code will be sent when calling the LoginUserIfNeeded method? I need to send it via SMS and not to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram servers decide by themselves through which method to send the code initially.

However if the user did not receive the code (eventually after a given timeout), he can request the code to be sent through an alternative method:

**In WTelegramClient, this is done by returning an empty string for "verification_code"** *(typically, only on the first try)*

You should probably first check through which medium Telegram sent the code:
The `client.OnOther` event receives a [Auth_SentCode](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/auth.sentCode) object specifying details (`type`) about the transmitted verification code. Then you can decide to reply the empty string only if it was transmitted through a medium you don't have access to.

You can check via the `Auth_SentCode.next_type` field which method will be used to send the code on the next try. (and you can possibly reply an empty verification_code again to try yet another method)

Additionally, on the call to `LoginUserIfNeeded` you can pass a [CodeSettings](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/codeSettings) instance which offer some limited options about the enabled methods for sending of the code.

⚠️⚠️ EDIT: Since February 2023, it's no longer possible to receive verification code by SMS with third-party libraries. Verification code can still be sent via various medias: other App sessions, email, phone call or device notifications